# Can we change [array-manipulation] to [array]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently, we have some tags which can be used to indicate what sorts of data answers will work with: [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number), [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string), [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation), [date](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date), and so on. One of those sticks out from the rest: [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation), which has `-manipulation` unnecessarily appended.

Interestingly, [array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array) *does* exist...but as a synonym, while [date](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date) has [date-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date-manipulation) as a synonym (and [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) and [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) have no synonyms at all). This is obviously inconsistent. The added `-manipulation` doesn't add anything useful, as [array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array) would still clearly indicate a challenge involves the manipulation of arrays, just as [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) indicates the manipulation of strings.

I doubt there's any intentional reason for this; [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation) was created a while after [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) and [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string), and it's likely nobody really thought about it (though it evidently confused some people, if [array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array) was created and made a synonym).

Fixing this wouldn't be too difficult, just requiring some moderator actions (removing the current [array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array), making a new one, and merging [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation) with it). Should we do this?

Comment: For visibility, as it was only mentioned in chat, no, this would require more than just making [array-manipulation] a synonym of [array], if we wanted to actually retag all existing questions. A moderator would have to delete the existing [array] tag, remove the synonym, approve the [array-manipulation] -> [array] synonym, then merge the two. Which shouldn't take more than a few minutes, but *is* more work than just approving a synonym

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I'll edit that into the question. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: I think we should. Your arguments in the question are convincing. Maybe you post an answer saying something like "Yes, for the reasons explained in the question", so we can vote on it?

Comment: @LuisMendo done

Answer (score 17):

## Yes, for the reasons explained in the question

I've posted this answer so we can vote on it.

Comment: (+1 from me, but I can't vote on my own answer)

Answer (score -7):

## No, because it's not worth the effort

I've posted this answer so we can vote on it.

Comment: (-1 from me, but I can't vote on my own answer)

Comment: Please don't post answers you don't agree with.  Let someone else who has the opinion post it so they can explain their reasoning.  If noone is willing to post an answer like that then we already know that there isn't much support for the idea and we don't need a poll.

Comment: @GrainGhost Sorry, I didn't know that was a policy. I was acting on [pre](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4672)[ce](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5544)[de](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1957)[nt](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4914)